# SSIS query to Oracle date column

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date, ssis, etl

On Windows 2016 server, SQL Server 2016 and VSDT 2017. Oracle `start_date` value (yyyy-mm-dd) but defined `vachar2(10)`.

```sql
select ...
       start_date
       ...
```

> [OLE DB Source] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string".

I set it with Unicode string `[DT_WSTR]` in input/output column properties. There are other columns defined as `varchar2` in same query with no issue. I get an "ORA-1861" error when I tried using `TO_DATE`.

Comment: `SELECT TO_DATE(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM ...`

Comment: `select start_date from your_table where validate_conversion(start_date as date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = 0`

Comment: If you still have problems with this column after trying the solution/troubleshooting advised in the comments above, please post your to_date statement and a sample of the data  in the start_date column.

Comment: Tried that and no row returned. when tried TO_CHAR got something like 2020-07-01 and TO_DATE got something like 01-JUL-20. Weird thing is that there are other fields defined as VARCHAR2 in Oracle. Only field has date value caused the issue.

Comment: In SQLDevloper, TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS START_DATE  --> returns 10-JUL-20, 17-OCT-19, 20-FEB-20,...and (null). Column was defined VARCHAR2(10) but date value in it. There are other columns defined as VARCHAR2(10) too, but don't cause SSIS to failed. Very weird.

Comment: TO_CHAR, TO_DATE, TRIM, SUBSTR,....seems not helping